# What main stat should I get for sands with Yanfei?

Tags: genshin-impact

I'm building Yanfei as a main dps carry for my team, and I have heard that Yanfei struggles with getting her burst frequently. Yet when I ask for other's opinions on what main stat to put on the sands artifact, most people suggest ATK% and not Energy Recharge. In particular, [this youtuber (timestamp marked)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yez1jO-QzAU&t=396s) suggests to not have Energy Recharge as a main stat, but to rather look for it in the substats.

May I receive some informed opinions on this matter? Can someone explain why ATK% may be better than Energy Recharge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT：Thanks to Childe，just find out a huge mistake of mine. I have calculate the 247 EM wrong. It should only provide 41.7%， not 58.7%.
Also, I have Added the calculation of damage for using Mappa Mare.

You should use elemental mastery if you have Xingqiu and using a weapon that provide percentage ATK（Or if you use Bennett.）.

Let's do some math.

Yanfei base attack at level 90 is 240, let's use Three weapon, Favonius Codex，Memory of Dust，and Lost Prayer to the Sacred Winds to calculate damage for Yanfei's charge attack at talent level 10(without calculating scarlet, damage increase, and crits) for ATK sand and EM sand. Let's made up a sub-stats for Artifacts, 30% ATK increase, 60 EM, 50 ATK total.

Favonius Codex: 4 star weapon，provide 510 base attack on 90 level, no percentage attack increase.

- ATK sand：grant 46.6% ATK increase, adding 30% from sub-stats, which will provide 76.6%*750=574~575 ATK. Total attack equals 750+575+311(From Feather)+50(From sub-stats)=1686 attack. 60 EM from sub-stats equals 11.4% damage increase for Vaporize, and using 4 WoF artifact will increase Vaporize by 15%, total increase is 26.4%. Damage without calculating damage increase, critical, and defense is 1686*1.5(vaporize)*1.264(vaporize damage increase)*1.8822(skill)=6016~6017 damage.
- EM sand： grant 187 EM，which is 247 EM total，brings us 41.7% vaporize damage increase，adding 4 WoF artifact to it equals 56.7% increase. And the ATK from percentage attack is 750*0.3=225. The finial ATK is 750+225+50+311=1336. Final damage is 1336 * 1.5 * 1.567 * 1.8822=5910～5911

Memory of Dust：5 star weapon，provides 608 base ATK，49.6 percentage attack.

- ATK sand：grant 46.6 percentage attack，total up to 126.6 percentagr attack，which is 848*1.266=1073～1074 ATK. Final attack is 848+1074+50+311=2283 ATK. Base on other information from previous part，final damage is 2283 * 1.5 * 1.264 * 1.8822=8147 damage.
- EM sand ：56.7% Vaporize damage increase，79.6% attack increase. 848*0.796=675 ATK，final ATK is 848+675+50+311=1884 ATK. Final damage 1884 * 1.5 * 1.567 * 1.8822=8335.

Lost Prayer to the Sacred Winds：5 star weapon, provide 608 base ATK.

- ATK sand: total percent attack increase is 76.6%, which means 649~650 ATK. Final ATK is 848+650+50+311=1859. Final damage equals 1859 * 1.5 * 1.266 * 1.8822=6644~6645.
- EM sand: total percent attack increase is 30%. Final attack is 848+254+50+311=1463. Final damage is 1463 * 1.5 * 1.567 * 1.8822=6472.

So from those three calculation，if your weapon have percentage ATK，you should use EM sand because the ATK is been delute. And if you have a lot ATK increase from sub-stat of artifact and no EM，you could use it too.

Then，if you use Bennett，use EM sand too. Let‘s do the calculation again on Lost Prayer to the Sacred Winds. A 10 level elemental burst bennett with Prototype Rancour will provide 764 Attack（Base Attack 756*101%）

- ATK sand damage：2623 * 1.5 * 1.266 * 1.8822=9375
- EM sand damage：2227 * 1.5 * 1.567 * 1.8822=9852

By the way, keep in mind that the damage is only for comparing EM sand and ATK sand, not for weapon compare, so don’t say that Memory of Sand is better than Lost Prayer to the Sacred Winds base on my calculations. My calculation didn’t count the damage increase(fire damage increase and other) and critical damage, those will not effect ATK and EM comparison, but will surely effect weapon comparison.

ADDED:

Mappa Mare: 4 star weapon, provide 565 base attack and 100 EM.

- ATK sand: 76.6% ATK, final ATK is 805+617+50+311=1783. 160 EM=28.5% increase，adding 4 WoF equals 43.5%. Final damage is 1783 * 1.5 * 1.435 * 1.8822=7224.
- EM sand：30% ATK，final ATK is 805+242+50+311=1408. 347 EM，55.3 increase plus 15% equals 70.3 increase. Final damage is 1408 * 1.5 * 1.703 * 1.8822=6770.

Comment: Why would you ever want to run an EM sands when you can run Mappa Mare for an EM boost or the ever more popular Widsith?

Comment: Will Xingqiu work well with Yanfei rotation? Especially since Yanfei will use her E quite often.

Comment: @justhalf Xingqiu works great with almost every pryo character.   His elemental burst will generates sword rain which deals  hydro DMG even when you are using Yanfei, you only need to use Xingqiu’s elemental skill each 20 second, and use elemental burst when it is available, the rest of the time you are free to use any character and you will get a decent amount of damage from Xingqiu and increase your Yanfei(or other pryo character)’s damage by 50%(even higher if you have some elemental mastery.) because the vaporize effect.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, seeing these numbers greatly reassures me.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest answer, *in general*:

- If you're a main DPS, you run an ATK sands
- If you're a burst/support and have a heavy burst cost, you run ER sands.

In this case, Yanfei's kit only allows her to be a main DPS, not a sub-DPS or even a support -- both her burst and skill is designed to augment her charged attacks, and rely on you keeping Yanfei on the field as long as possible.

So switching to an ER sands is pointless. You can easily generate energy by having another Pyro unit on your team, such as Bennett who will not only serve as a DPS buff but also an excellent battery.  Having an 80 energy burst is not a big deal when you have 3 other units in your team that can supply energy orbs, resonance, or buffs to have her burst come back quicker.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but of course, Yanfei with energy cost being 80 is one of the highest in the game, but at the same time her kit only allows for her to be main dps. This is the conflict I'm facing with.

Comment: Suspect EM sands is also viable in a vaporize team, potentially beating ATK % depending sub stats, and weapons

Comment: @Pritt The only thing her burst enables her to do is to slightly change up her normal attack strings to get a charged attack in faster. Otherwise, your normal gameplay loop is building up 3 stacks of Scarlet Seals, then using a Charged Attack, rinsing and repeating.  Yanfei's skill gives her 3 stacks of Scarlet Seals right away, so it's not very important to have her burst constantly up as you need to rotate your other characters in to setup elemental reactions and whatnot

Comment: And like I said -- 80 energy cost is nothing when you have a proper battery.  Beidou teams often run Fischl, an excellent Electro battery, in conjunction with her to augment her 80 energy burst, with little to no issues.  Ayaka teams will have a Cryo battery with her like Rosaria/Ayaka/Diona to augment her 80 energy burst.  With all 3 examples I've mentioned so far you also gain elemental resonance which further adds to your damage in some degree.

Comment: I think it would be worth while to talk about EM sands.